# RESTEasy Asynchronous HTTP with Spring MVC

Tags: spring, http, rest, asynchronous, resteasy

Is there any handy way to use RESTEasy Asynchronous HTTP support (in my case on Tomcat 6) in conjunction with the Spring MVC framework. I've found useful articles on using RESTEasy with Spring, but none that cover asynchronous support, which appears to be a bit of a thorn at present, due to requring a different Servlet class depending on the container (Tomcat6CometDispatcherServlet for Tomcat, for example).

Thanks,
FB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody interested, I ended up having to use the Tomcat6CometDispatcherServlet in preference to the Spring DispatcherServlet to get my application working.

I still have the Spring ContextLoaderListener in place to create the various beans within my  Application Context, but have to use less than ideal means of accessing these from within my Controller classes, which are now JAX-RS annotated rather than Spring MVC annotated. (There are various articles a quick Google will uncover on accessing the Spring context programmatically.)

Here's a cleaned up version of my web.xml (nothing earth-shattering, but perhaps it will have some useful hints for somebody!):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.4" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<display-name>myapp</display-name>
<description>My App</description>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:log4j.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
        <param-value>myapp.root</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
       <filter-name>TrustedIPFilter</filter-name>
       <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>TrustedIPFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>    
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>    

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
       <servlet-name>PollServlet</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.Tomcat6CometDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>PollServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/poll/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
        <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/uncaughtException.jsp</location>
    </error-page>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sample app using Comet, Bayeux, Java, Maven and a Raphael JS frontend and wrote a blog post about it, you can use it as a base for your app, just wrapping the current service code in REST.

http://geeks.aretotally.in/thinking-in-reverse-not-taking-orders-from-yo

Hopefully it will help you.

Comment: Thanks Felipe. I took a look at this, but can't see how to access any sources for your app...